# SKPaymentTransactionObserver crashes in purchasing status

Tags: ios6, crash, storekit

I'm new to in-app purchases, and following the tutorials, I've got the product request going, an observer, and everything.  However, at the point that the modal purchase dialog comes up (while the observer thinks the transaction is in "Purchasing" state, the app freezes up.

In the logs, I'm getting a crazy EXC_BAD_ACCESS error right here:

```
0x35b822b4:  blx    0x35f9bb18                ; symbol stub for: -[_UIHostedTextServiceSession dismissTextServiceAnimated:]
0x35b822b8:  movs   r0, #0      <--EXC_BAD_ACCESS (Code=1, address=0x69466469)
```

The interesting thing is that even though the app freezes, the purchase process continues, although with the app frozen, it will never finalize.

Based on some of the other posts I've seen, I've tried it on the simulator, multiple devices, as well as using ad hoc (TestFlight) distribution in case it was an issue with the development cert, and nothing works.

One possibility I haven't seen an answer for is that the product in question hasn't yet been approved.  I assume that, since I'm connecting in sandbox mode, and since the product request process is clearly getting data back from the app store, that wasn't an issue.  Is it possible that an un-approved store item is causing the problem?

If it is the case that the unapproved SKU is breaking things, I'm really confused because iTunes Connect indicates that I can't submit a SKU except with a new version of the app for review, and, well, if I can't test the store feature, I don't want to submit that new version.  Anyone here have any experience with this who can tell me why everything is going kablooey?

EDIT: One other thing that might be important is that the purchase button is in a modal push (specifically a page-curl) view.  I know that Twitter requests can't be called from modal views.  Is there a reason a store transaction couldn't be done in this view?

Comment: In order to answer the view-activated-by-a-modal-transition question, I added a navigation controller into the storyboard and instead just did a a transition within that environment, and I got the same error.

Comment: The other strange thing is that, even though I've emptied out my credentials in the settings for iTunes/AppStore, when I run this transaction, at the time of failure, it's clearly trying to re-use one of the early test IDs that I created, and which I haven't used since.  It's as if some bad data is cached somewhere, preventing me from moving on...

Comment: I've put more details in a thread at the developer forums.  If anyone's interested, that's at:  

https://devforums.apple.com/message/789501

Comment: And the issue is resolved. Apple's sample code was for non-ARC projects.  Redefining the scope of my observer fixed the problem!

Comment: Thanks for the link to the dev forum. I was pulling my hair out trying to debug code that worked pre-iOS6, but started crashing without a "normally" symbolicated crash.

Comment: Chris: It's a pleasure. People here are so helpful, I'm glad one of my questions has helped someone else too!